# how to move my android studio project from my pc to my another pc with a different user name?

Tags: android, project, migrate

I installed a new windows with a different username. I have my android studio project files saved, now i want to use the same project in android studio after i installed the new windows. by the way the app is already published in google play store.

Regards

Comment: You might want to learn how to use Github, by the way

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to simply copy the project directory to any location on the new computer and then open it as a project from within Studio.

Comment: The project directory contains specific information about the previous file paths. It could get confused when importing

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, the actual code doesn't care where it exists on the file system. And you can't easily get code from an app on Google Play

Assuming it's using Gradle, at a minimum, you need to only copy the `app` folder, `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`.

Then you can open the `build.gradle` file in Android Studio, and it'll ask to import the whole thing as a project

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the old SDK folder and it worked.